# icCube - InterpolateRGBColors based on min & max values?

Tags: colors, mdx, interpolation, iccube

I understand that InterpolateRGBColors function is returning a color by position of value between 0 and 1... So its seems to be doable only with percentages, not numbers...

Is there a way to have the same functionality, but based on the min and max values returned in a set ?

What I want is to attribute colors to my measure but in a range of min([Measures].[NbSejours]) to max([Measures].[NbSejours]) ( not 0 to 1)...

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[color] AS 
    InterpolateRGBColors(
        [Measures].[NbSejours] 
        ,rgb(176,224,230)
        ,rgb(135,206,235)
        ,rgb(0,191,255)
        ,rgb(100,149,237)
        ,rgb(0,0,255)
        ,rgb(0,0,139)
        ,rgb(25,25,112) 
    ), BACK_COLOR=currentCellValue()
SELECT 
  {
    {[Measures].[NbSejours]}
   ,[Measures].[color]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    NonEmpty
    (
      [Etablissement].[Etablissement].[Etablissement].ALLMEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[NbSejours]
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {{[Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2013]}} ON 0
  FROM [Cube]
)
CELL PROPERTIES 
  STYLE
 ,CLASSNAME
 ,VALUE
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE;
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: (Interesting question: I'm guessing the `icCube` guys will pick this one up to help you)

Comment: Im not ICcube expert, but common sense says you should just try RANK() function outputs for the whole set and then get number for yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[InterpolateRGBColors](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/InterpolateRGBColors.php) expect a numerical between 0 and 1 for interpolation. So we need to scale our measure to ensure we get the right colors.

There is an example in our live demo , [here](http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=MDX%20Formatting).

What we need is to scale *[Measures].[NbSejours]* between 0,1. There are two no documented function in icCube DistributionFlat & DistributionRank.

A non efficient version

```
WITH
  SET [AxisX] AS  NonEmpty([Etablissement].Etablissement].Etablissement].ALLMEMBERS,[Measures].[NbSejours])
  FUNCTION distr(x_) as  DistributionFlat(  [AxisX], [Measures].[NbSejours], x_ )
  MEMBER [Measures].[color] AS 
InterpolateRGBColors(
    distr([Measures].[NbSejours]) 
    ,rgb(176,224,230)
    ,rgb(135,206,235)
    ,rgb(0,191,255)
    ,rgb(100,149,237)
    ,rgb(0,0,255)
    ,rgb(0,0,139)
    ,rgb(25,25,112) 
), BACK_COLOR=currentCellValue()
....
```

Once I got a bit of time I'll write a version using Vectors ([here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Vector.php) and [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_types/vector.php)) that is more performant as in the example above we calculate every time the values for the set.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot @ic3! This is exactly what I need in terms of functionality... But have to admit this is not efficient... :-(

Comment: Try adding this to the first line of your MDX  //#Cache( mode = 'ALL', maxSize = 42000 )

Answer (score 0):

I don'r know `icCube` so the following might not work, even though I have used standard functions. As @George commented you can use the standard `RANK` function to find each members relative position.

You will need to feed that value into the definition of `[Measures].[color]`...

```
WITH 
SET [estMembersOrdered] AS
  ORDER(
      [Etablissement].[Etablissement].[Etablissement].ALLMEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[NbSejours]
     ,BDESC
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[rnkEtablissement] AS 
   RANK(
     [Etablissement].[Etablissement].CURRENTMEMBER
     , [estMembersOrdered]
   )
MEMBER [Measures].[color] AS 
    InterpolateRGBColors(
        [Measures].[NbSejours] 
        ,rgb(176,224,230)
        ,rgb(135,206,235)
        ,rgb(0,191,255)
        ,rgb(100,149,237)
        ,rgb(0,0,255)
        ,rgb(0,0,139)
        ,rgb(25,25,112) 
    ), BACK_COLOR=currentCellValue()
SELECT 
  {
    {[Measures].[NbSejours]}
   ,[Measures].[color]
   ,[Measures].[rnkEtablissement] 
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    NonEmpty
    (
      [Etablissement].[Etablissement].[Etablissement].ALLMEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[NbSejours]
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {{[Periode].[Periode].[All-M].&[2013]}} ON 0
  FROM [Cube]
)
CELL PROPERTIES 
  STYLE
 ,CLASSNAME
 ,VALUE
 ,FORMATTED_VALUE;
```